# How do you correctly set DSN? [ERR: No DNSKEY records found ; The CNAME RRset was not signed by any keys in the chain-of-trust]

Tags: heroku, dsn, namecheap

I successfully deployed my project on Heroku. The problems occurred when I wanted to set a custom domain for it (bought namecheap.com).

In neither Heroku nor Namecheap I get an error. Everything is correct, but somehow I cannot reach the page, and running an analysis on the following website returns these errors:

https://dnsviz.net/d/amsterdamtruffles.com/dnssec/

Errors:

```
-No DNSKEY records found.
-The CNAME RRset was not signed by any keys in the chain-of-trust.
```

Can anybody point me in the right direction to solve these errors?

Comment: Most domains don't have DNSSEC I don't think. Why do you think that's the problem?

Comment: You have set the root domain as a CNAME. I don't think that's allowed in general, and that might be tripping up something somewhere along the way. But FWIW I can curl the domain fine and it works fine on my phone.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this occur, and the cause was setting the root domain (`@`) CNAME to my.github.io.  The correct setup shown below, has the root and www pointed to the github.io servers, and also includes the www CNAME redirection and github pages TXT domain verification record.[image]

Finally, there is a CNAME record in my github pages folder with the domain name to display, and with the errant root CNAME record gone on namecheap, it all works.